# Saving and Loading the Game (Automatically or Manually) via Internal Storage Only (Tablet PC Issues)

Tags: libgdx, music, loading, savegame, filesystem

Here is my question. When making a game app for Android, I considered first the device. It's no problem to save progress everything (from levels to records) on a smartphone because it has an SD Card slot. Exception to this, the tablet PC, it can really nothing but on internal only storage.

For example, I'm using this tutorial for audio spectrum (*see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5cN1VzZXcdo*) that involves copying from internal to external in order to detect frequency. It works on the desktop but not on the Android device (Tablets only [i.e. *Google Nexus Tablet*]).

Is there a way to optimize save/load game problems due to internal/external device issues? Plus, additionally, what's the reason why my device won't work on tablets, except the desktop, while testing the audio spectrum code and why? Also, is it the same with saving/loading game?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally understand about **Preferences**. Here's the example and observe the comments. Take note that this is sample from my previous projects.

```
public class Temporary_Database 
{
    //TODO __________[ Field data ]__________
    public Preferences pref_1;
    public Preferences pref_2;
    public String male_name;
    public String female_name;



    //TODO __________[ Temporary Database's Constructor ]__________
    public Temporary_Database()
    {
        pref_1 = Gdx.app.getPreferences("male-identity"); // You can use any String ID written within the parameter.
        pref_2 = Gdx.app.getPreferences("female-identity");
    }



    //TODO __________[ Loading Methods ]__________
    public void Load_Name_of_Male(String male_name)
    {
        male_name = pref_1.getString("Male's Name", male_name); // "male_name", for example, is the String object and this is where you recall the value itself through loading it.
        this.male_name = male_name;
    }

    public void Load_Name_of_Female(String female_name)
    {
        female_name = pref_2.getString("Male's Name", female_name);
        this.female_name = female_name;
    }










//TODO __________[ Saving Methods ]__________
public void Save_Name_of_Male(String male_name)
{
    pref_1.putString("Male's Name", male_name); // "male_name" is the String object and this is where you change the value itself through loading it.
    pref_1.flush(); // Flush to save changes.
}

public void Save_Name_of_Female(String female_name)
{
    pref_2.putString("Male's Name", female_name);
    pref_2.flush();
}



    //TODO __________[ Set Value Method ]__________
    public String Get_Male_Name()
    {
        return male_name; // Uses as the new value itself after saving it and preferred to be used in loading action.
    }

    public String Get_Female_Name()
    {
        return female_name;
    }
```

}

Comment: Hope you cant count on your knowledge, David. Remember, instead of asking questions, why don't you discover it? Observe and find out. You'll only ask questions only if you find something not familiar to. Anyways, how does this using preferences work? Can it be also used for storing as database especially in MMORPG games where you stored items in the inventory? Just a question that I would like to know.

Comment: It could be @TredeciesNocturne but it needs a lot of array for that specific item or rows. I haven't experienced using database using only 'Preferences' and arrays. Unless, I can made a good method for this.